# If statement inside nested 'for' loops is evaluating only once - python

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, nested-loops

I am writing a code which compares file1 (single column of entries) with file 2 (3 column of entries) and fetch matched records from file 2 on basis of first column. The problem is that it is evaluating the loop only once.

File1:

```
ABC

DEF

JKL
```

File2:

```
IJK,123,SDF

ABC,456,HJK

QWE,876,GFT

JKL,098,HGF
```

.....

My code:

```
for entry in fh_file1:
    mir = entry.strip('\n')
    print(mir)
    for row in fh_file2:
        row_splt = row.split(',')             
        print(row_splt[0])
        if mir in row_splt[0]:
            print (row.strip('\n'))
        else:
            pass
```

Result from that code:

is just the match of first entry of file 1:

```
ABC 456 HJK
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Why `if mir in row_splt[0]:` not `if mir == row_splt[0]:`?

Comment: This sort of question is asked very often, but I am having trouble finding a good duplicate.

Comment: @tauran That's not even nearly the same. One checks for exact equality, the other is a substring/element (depending on the types, didn't look at the code too closely) search.

Comment: @delnan: I know. But I don't understand why he uses `in` here.

Comment: I don't see any commas in your data. Why is your `string.split()` set to split on commas?

Comment: @Simeon, Code wombat and Aaron dufor: First I tried with the old techniques suggested in one my earlier question but couldn't make it to work that I still dont understand why. Second, I wanted to know why it is being evaluated once as I had same problem many a times. So, for me it was important to know why always such loops are evaluated once. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `fh_file2.seek(0)` before the second `for` loop to start over at the beginning of the file.

You'd be better served, however, by reading it into memory once:

```
file2_lines = fh.file2.readlines()
```

then iterating over `file2_lines`. Reading the file from disk for each line in another file is going to be very slow.

Comment: Thanks. The 'seek' suggestion did the job perfectly. I tried to find a solution online but couldn't find it anywhere. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Files are streams of data. When you loop over them, you read them a line at a time. At the end of the inner loop, that file has reached the end. It will not start again at the beginning for the next iteration of the outer loop, because that's not how files work.

You should usually read the file into memory first: `list(fh_file1)` will give you a `list` of lines that you can loop over as many times as you like.

Comment: `fh_file2` is the problem, not `fh_file1`, and `file.readlines()` is usually more efficient and clearer than `list(file)`. Also, instead of reading everything into memory you can re-wind or re-open the file.